# Angular 10 - Chart.js to draw chart in Array with convas id on runtime

Tags: html5-canvas, chart.js, angular10

I have a requirement to draw charts based on the data objects available in database. To handle this, i have created the Object Array and to use the convas ID, i have a placeholder in Object. In HTML, i am assigning the ID from Object. But, i am getting the bellow error -

> Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Data Class:

```
export class SetPressureData {
  popPressure: number;
  seatingPressure: number;
  conclusion: string;
  conclusionOperatorComment: string;
  isSetPressureChartAvailable = false;
  chartName: string;
  showOnCert: boolean=true;
}
```

My code in .ts file like this:

```
setPressureTestLinechart: [];
....
if (_testResultTS.sensorId == SensorId.PZT_01 || _testResultTS.sensorId == SensorId.PT_PT05) {
  this.chartName = 'setPressureChart' + this.setPressureDataCount;
  this.setPressureData.chartName = this.chartName;
  this.prepareCharts(this.setPressureTestLinechart, this.chartName, _testResultTS.values, -1, 1);
  this.setPressureData.isSetPressureChartAvailable = true;
}

prepareCharts(chartName: Chart, chartCanvas: string, tsSample: TimeSeriesSample[],
  minValOffset ? : number, maxValOffset ? : number) {
  let timeStamps = [];
  let values = [];
  let minValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  let maxValue = Number.MIN_VALUE;

  chartName = new Chart(chartCanvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: timeStamps,
      datasets: [{
        pointRadius: 0,
        data: values,
        borderColor: '#3e95cd',
      }]
    },
    options: chartOptions
  });
}
```

And my code in HTML like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="certificateData.setPressureResults?.length>0;else pressureTestAborted">
    <div *ngFor="let setPressureData of certificateData.setPressureResults, let i=index">
        <!--Iterate over the Array for all Set Pressure Test Executed -->
        <div id="{{i}}" *ngIf="setPressureData.showOnCert">
            <span>
                <br />
                Test #{{i+1}}
            </span>
            <input type="checkbox" (click)="updateShowFlag(i)" />Please check, if not required on certificate
            <mat-card-content>
                <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 41%;">
                    <span class="field-label-prep">Pop Pressure:</span><span class="data">{{setPressureData.popPressure}}</span> <span class="units">bar</span><br />
                    <span class="field-label-prep">Seating Pressure:</span> <span class="data">{{setPressureData.seatingPressure}}</span><span class="units">bar</span> <br />
                    <div class="col-style-prep" *ngIf="setPressureData.conclusionOperatorComment">
                        <span class="field-label-prep">Operator Comment:</span><br />
                        <span class="comment">{{setPressureData.conclusionOperatorComment}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block; width: 48%;">
                    <canvas class="chart-style" height="85" id="{{setPressureData.chartName}}"></canvas>
                    <span class="time-caption">[Time in mm:ss]</span>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="setPressureData.conclusion!=null" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 11%;">
                    <span
                        class="result-status-column"
                        [ngClass]="{ 'testOpResults-Green': (setPressureData.conclusion === testOperationresults.Approved ||setPressureData.conclusion === testOperationresults.Performed),
                                                                                'testOpResults-Red': setPressureData.conclusion === testOperationresults.Failed,
                                                                                'testOpResults-Orange': setPressureData.conclusion === testOperationresults.Aborted }"
                    >
                        {{setPressureData.conclusion}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Array Iteration-->
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Chart.js` cannot find a `canvas` with an `id` that matches the specified  `chartCanvas` at the time when you create the chart.

```
new Chart(chartCanvas, {
  ...
```

Due to the `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` directives in the `HTML` template, the `canvas` elements are included in the `DOM` only once the `certificateData.setPressureResults` array contains some elements. The Angular automatic change detection mechanism is normally responsible to keep the `DOM` synchronized with the data contained in the `component` class.

To solve your problem, you need to manually trigger change detection after updatating `certificateData.setPressureResults` but before creating the chart(s). This can be done through a call of [`ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges).

Therefore, the code of your `component` class would have to be changed as follows:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, ...) {
  ...
}

// trigger change detection wherever it fits
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```